# The app's res has hundreds of mp3 files

Tags: java, android, mp3

After I generated the signed APK, the size is about 370MB.
It's huge，almost more than a game.

I found another application in the app store, which has similar functions.
It also can listen hundreds of mp3 files, but it's just 54MB in size.

The small application can be used without internet.
So it stores the song files inside the application, not on a server.

In addition, it runs on a mac.
My application runs on the phone.

So what should I do to have a smaller app?
Just compress the song files?

Comment: @ zhen I don't understand "I have write a app that have hundreds mp3" it means you have save hundred mp3 in your application.?

Comment: @DileepPatel yes, there are hundred mp3 in res

Comment: `In addition, it runs on a mac.` ... and you found it on the Google Play Store?! No. That's **impossible**.

Comment: I hope you are not trying to publish songs with copyrights.

Comment: @eldo  don't worry. they are just a few audio, not songs with copyrights. I have compress and convert to .ogg format. now the app's size is about 80MB !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `.mp3` files in your app use `.ogg` format audio files which are extremely small in size as compared to .mp3 files, are android compatible and have a very good quality. You can easily convert your .mp3 files to .ogg files by using any audio converter available online.

Comment: compress audio files ,then convert to .ogg format.

Answer (score 0):

in these kind of applications all the data is on a server on the internet and the application either download them or use streaming to load the song files from the server !!!!!!

of-course its insane to have your data in your application !!! even that application you mentioned with the size of 50mb can be of lower size lets say around 5mb.